# Insert a JSP inside another with Spring-MVC and Jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp

I developing a web project which has a navigation bar, a wrapper envolving the components that are switched, etc. At this moment, i have links for every element in the navigation bar. If you click the link a new JSP page is loaded with the same menu bar, css, etc...

Is it possible to load with jquery a jsp inside another? I decided to do this because i have a jsp in my project which renders an Ext-js table. This table needs a Ext-js stylesheet and this stylesheet changes my styles. So i decided to try load the jsp inside another in order to preserve my styles.

Thank you

Comment: Show us the generated HTML.

Comment: rats.. i forgot to include the jstl libray in this page. Thank you for answer @JB. I changed the question to a new one because the previous question was a silly mistake

Comment: That's what I suspected. Wanted you to find it out by yourself, and get the reflex of looking at the generated HTML.

Comment: Your advice helped me. thank you @JB